# tmux: Keep scroll position when changing session

Tags: tmux, scrolling

Sometimes I'm scrolling up a log file and need to switch sessions, so open the session menu with prefix-s. This causes tmux to forget the window's scroll position, so that when I return it's at the bottom of the log file.

Is there any way to keep scroll position when switching session?

Answer (score 0):

use `less` to read your log file ?
Or use `screen` ?
I think that could be 2 solutions.

Comment: I can't use less as these are usually live logs using `tail -f`. As for screen, this is a bit annoying, but not annoying enough to leave tmux!

Comment: :D screen is so powerfull, but I definetly understand your problem using it :D   well good luck with that.

Comment: I'm sure screen's fine too. It's more that I never got really into it and Tmux seems to be a good choice for the future.